# error: Unable to find package [packageName] as a dependency

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to add reference to nuget package A which has a dependency to nuget package B. and when I use the command

dotnet add package to add the package reference to package A. I get following error:

error: Unable to find package B. I was not able to find any package called B in at least the same nuget stream. I thought the entire point of nuget packages is that they are self contained and can be referenced individually.

Since I am not able to find the package in the same Nuget server, I have no idea where to look for it. Also, I do have access tot he source code of  Package A and the .csproj file there has `Project reference` to project B. I have no idea where, along the line it because a nuget reference.

Is there anything that I should be doing that I am not doing here? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a package has a dependency on another package, NuGet needs both packages to be available. Though you might install one, the dependent packages are installed automatically.

If you have source code, try creating packageA again from the source code. It should automatically create the packageB because of Project to Project reference relationship. You can either upload them to the NuGet Server or put it in a folder and use that folder as an additional feed.